# How Can I add trading view chart in my react website with custom data?

Tags: reactjs, charts, cryptojs

I want to use a trading view chart in my react project with my custom data. How can I add this?

I want a trading view chart like this.
[chart demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrHW4.png)

Comment: You could build it yourself or search npmjs for an existing package to use.

Comment: I don't find any npm package where I can add custom data